# Handling Nullable Json Response when using RESTFul Technical Profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the [REST technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to retrieve data from a claims provider.

The JSON payload that is returned includes values that are optional for some users.

- When the value is not set, it will be returned as the null literal
- When the value is set, it will be returned as a string that contains an ISO 8601 formatted date time.

User Group 1 (well formed ISO 8601 string)

```
{
 "OptionalIso8601DateTime" : "2022-12-11T12:34:56Z"
}
```

User Group 2 (null literal)

```
{
 "OptionalIso8601DateTime" : null
}
```

AAD B2C appears to have two distinct behaviours when processing the JSON Payload of a REST endpoint (that are not configurable) which results the inability for a claims mapping to be defined that does not result in a server_error response being generated for one group of users.

Behaviours:

1. All strings that are determined to contain valid dateTime string literals are automatically cast to dateTime

- as a result, a valid dateTime string literal can only be mapped to claims of type dateTime

2. The null literal value is automatically cast as a string - and populated with the empty string value

- as a result, the null literal can only be mapped to claims of type string

I have attempted to define mappings using the string and dateTime data types, however neither is able to function for both user groups.

Observations:

| AAD B2C Claim DataType | Payload Value | Result | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | null | "" | null literal is converted to empty string |
| string | "2022-12-11T12:34:56Z" | AADB2C99072 | dateTime cannot be converted to string |
| dateTime | null | AADB2C99072 | string cannot be converted to dateTime |
| dateTime | "2022-12-11T12:34:56Z" | 1670762096 | value emitted as number (unix epoch) as per default OpenId Jwt Issuance Policy |

I have no control over the format of the payload that is returned by the external system. Ideally, they would omit the claim in the event that there is no value, however returning the null literal is valid according to the Json specification.

I am looking for a mechanism to be able to map the data (specifically the case where the value is not null) as a valid dateTime so that it can be passed to downstream applications - that does not result in authentication failing with error AADB2C99072 for one set of users.

Ideally, if there were some way to configure AAD B2C to ignore null values (treat them as absent from the payload), or for the null to be preserved so that there is not an error when the empty string is set as the value of the dateTime claim.

Comment: What I do is to use a proxy API that calls the real API. Use the proxy API to return a consistent value.

Comment: @rbrayb I am hoping to avoid the introduction of additional external components if possible. Introduction of a service such as a function app would necessitate downgrading the SLA from 99.99% to 99.95%.

Comment: I would also note that I am only using the REST technical profile as a workaround for the fact that the [OpenID Connect  Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile) cannot call the UserInfo endpoint.

Comment: If you use custom policies, you can - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userinfo-endpoint?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. Not quite sure I understand?

Comment: @rbrayb it is the UserInfo endpoint of the Federated Identity provider that I need to call. That documentation is to allow AAD B2C to offer a UserInfo Endpoint to downstream Relying Parties. Interesting note - the [OAuth2 Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile#user-info-endpoint-metadata) does have built in support for calling the UserInfo endpoint - despite it having nothing to do with the OAuth2 Protocol.

Comment: Whilst this conversation is somewhat off topic, Microsoft have confirmed (in a previously raised premier support case) that the Open Id Connect Technical Profile can only access claims that are present in the id_token. If the Federated Identity Provider only supports returning a specific subset of claims from the UserInfo endpoint (as is the case with the Identity Provider I need to integrate with), then you have to implement the call yourself.